# How to identify Windows ISO version from Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, iso-image, dism

I downloaded a Windows 10 21H1 ISO file from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO), and I need to find out the specific version number, not just 21H1. From windows you can use the DISM command to locate that info, but how would I find that out on Kubuntu 21.04?

Comment: You won't be able to determine this information from Linux. However, Windows 10 21H1 ISO doesn't change, so it's always a specific version.  So you can simply determine the version of the ISO on a Windows machine.

Comment: The best solution is to use something like https://uupdump.net/ to download the 21H1 iso with all the available updates.